# Instagram API Access Token for public content for Testing

Tags: instagram, access-token, instagram-api

I´m trying my self with the Instagram API, but I can´t understand the whole acces_token thing.

I understand that it is for authorization to access information, but why is it so so hard to get a token to get public information ?

For example with facebook you just need a profile to get your personal access_token and with that you can gather information. Why is this not possible with Instagram or is there a way to get a access token that has public_content as a scope ?

I would like to have it seperate from my profile ofc. It is possible with Facebook that easily and it´s basicly the same company. 
And for example it´s possible to combine the App-ID & App Secretcode to use it as a access_token. Is this possible with Instagram ?

Am I missing something ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Instagram has to approve your app before you get full API access, people used to abuse the API, so they recently made this change. If its a one time thing, then just use a third party app that is already approved to gather information.

Comment: Any example for a app that is approved and shows my access token ?

Comment: you can use https://www.picodash.com to search and export data

Comment: A paid service for something that "simple"

Comment: what data do u want ?

Comment: I need information like follower, like and view count.

Comment: View count is a bit difficult I know but I have a solution for that.